# tf.dataset does not append batches

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I want to get tf.dataset to work. The code example below is working, but since I used `.batch(30)` I would expect that the output is in the form of (30, 300, 300, 1)?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

input_array = np.random.normal(size=(300, 300, 3))

def own_generator():
    yield (input_array, input_array)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(own_generator, (tf.float32, tf.float32)).batch(30)
data_iter = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(data_iter.initializer)
test_arr = sess.run(data_iter.get_next())

for tuple_elemnt in test_arr:
    print(tuple_elemnt.shape)
```

The output is:

```
(1, 300, 300, 3)
(1, 300, 300, 3)
```

Comment: Your generator only yields a single element, so no larger batch can be created.

Comment: Ohh, damn it. Your right. I didn't consider this. I'll add the new real working example to the question. You can post it as answer so that I can mark it as answered.

Comment: Well it's not like I provided a fix... You did that yourself. Note that you can also answer your own questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generator was falsely programmed. This is the working example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

input_array = np.random.normal(size=(300, 300, 3))

def own_generator():
    while True:
        yield input_array

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(own_generator, tf.float32).batch(30)
data_iter = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(data_iter.initializer)
test_arr = sess.run(data_iter.get_next())

print(test_arr.shape)
```